# I'm new to programming. My goal is to learn Objective-C but C has been easier to understand so far. Which direction should I go?

Tags: objective-c, c, new-operator

Would learning C before Objective-C be beneficial or just slow me down?  My goal is to make some useful applications for OSX.

Comment: Probably better on programmers.stackexchange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C is a superset of C, so C won't hurt you, and will probably even help a bit. Furthermore, some of OS X's frameworks, like CoreFoundation, expose a C interface, and you'll likely have to use them at some point anyway. *But* most OS X development uses Objective-C, so you'll eventually have to learn it anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I will probably just learn C first.  Programming has little to do with my career and is more of a side hobby, so I'll take my time and be thorough.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best books is Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X 3rd edition by Aaron Hillegass. That will get you started in learning Objective-C. That would be a good investment to see if you like how Objective-C and Mac OS X programming is.

[http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Programming-Mac-OS-3rd/dp/0321503619/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1295977786&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to write applications for iOS or Mac OS X then Objective-C gives you access to many useful free Apple frameworks; you simply can't ignore that.

If you are liking C then I think you'll love Objective-C. Once you get your mind around the idea of objects it should be pretty quick to comprehend. From there, you're really just learning which methods to call and for that Google (and this site) is your friend. Apple has done a great job of giving so much "for free"; you'll be amazed at what can be done with just a few lines of code!

Also, I would recommend "Programming in Objective-C 2.0". This was the book that I learned from and it really is well written.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the language that speaks to you the most. The first language you learn really in depth can become your native tongue, and can affect your perceptions of programming for your entire life. You may want to develop for OSX at the moment, but if C makes more sense to you, maybe someday you will be hacking the linux kernel!

Answer (score 0):

I think Obj C is the mid of C++ and Jave. So C++ would be more helpful than C.

But if your goal of learning Obj C is to make OSX apps, I think, you can skip C or C++ or Java. You can find many good Obj Books, tutorial, web documents.

Comment: Objective-C is C with a more Smalltalk-like object system attached, while C++ is based on Simula.  I'd say C would be more helpful, being quicker to learn.